# Odoo 10 - Extend view res_partner

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, qweb

I want to add a new tab in `res_partner` form view after tab "Accounting".

I am trying the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<odoo>
    <record id="foo_res_partner" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">Partner Extended View</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_partner_form"/>
        <field name="model">res.partner</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//page[@name='accounting']" position="after">
                <page string="Foo" name="foo" attrs="{'invisible': [('is_customer','=',False),]}">
                    <span>Foo</span>
                </page>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

I load the module and everything installs smoothly but then when you click on any customer card to open the `res.partner` form view no form view is opened at all and no error messages are shown in the logs.

Any help is welcomed.

Comment: Is the issue get solved, if you deactivate this view from ir.ui.view form view?

Answer (score 1):

**Solved Odoo 10 - Extend view res_partner**

You wrote something wrong in your code.I improve your code. Maybe this is useful for you.

```xml
<record id="foo_res_partner" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Partner Extended View</field>
    <field name="model">res.partner</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.view_partner_property_form"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//page[@name='accounting_disabled']" position="after">
            <page string="Foo" name="foo" attrs="{'invisible': [('customer','=',False)]}">
                <span>Foo</span>
            </page>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>
```